# Why this array of strings pass the wrong elemet to this function?

Tags: arrays, string, pointers, char, structure

This is part of my code:

```
typedef struct drink{
    char name[32];
    int price;
    struct drink* next;
}drink;

typedef struct pub{
    char name[32];
    drink* price_list;
    struct pub* next;
}pub;

pub *find_cheapest(pub *p, char **italok, int n)
{
   .
   .
   .
}
```

I would like to pass the `*italok[]` array to the `find_cheapest()` function but it fails to get the correct elements:
I would appreciate the help, thank you.

```
char *italok[] = {"Gosser", "Soproni"};
printf("\n%s\n", find_cheapest(p, italok, 2));
```

Comment: Are you calling the function `find_cheapest` from main() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> char *italok[] = {"Gosser", "Soproni"};

Here, you are declaring an `auto` variable `*italok[]`. `Auto`  variable lifetime begins when program execution enters the function or statement block and ends when execution leaves the block. So, the contents of `*italok[]` are no longer available in `find_cheapest` function.

There are two ways to sove it:

1. Static memory allocation : using `static variables`

The lifetime of `static variable` is equal to the lifetime of the program. Hence, its values are retained inside other function blocks also. `Change the auto variable to static`.
`static char *italok[] = {"Gosser", "Soproni"};`

2. Dynamic memory allocation : using `malloc()`

The lifetime of a dynamic object begins when memory is allocated for the object (e.g., by a call to `malloc()`) and ends when memory is deallocated. The values of the `malloc`'ed variables are retained inside other functions. So, allocate memory to `italok[]` using `malloc`.

```
char **italok = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         italok[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
     }
italok[0] = "Gosser";
italok[1] = "Soproni";
```

Similarly, declare `p` as a static or dynamic variable .